# pywintypes.error: (1400, 'GetMenu', 'Invalid window handle.')

Tags: python, handle, win32gui

I am using python API to remote control software called PLAXIS (Geotechnical software). And there are certain modules in PLAXIS that can be used by using the editor(its editor is SciTE) of this software. now, I am trying to run a code which I attached the part that I get an error on here. this code is supposed to get the results of a couple of simulations and give those to the user in an excel file. I debugged a couple of errors, but, I can not understand this error. I will appreciate your help if you could help me to fix this error.

```
`

Function:Close current file and open a new file
def Closeandopen(Number,path,subpath):
    assert type(Number)==str
    assert type(path)==str
    assert type(subpath)==str
    Menuid=win32gui.GetMenu(outwindow)
    SubMenuid=win32gui.GetSubMenu(Menuid,1)
    Openid=win32gui.GetMenuItemID(SubMenuid,0)
    CloseAllid=win32gui.GetMenuItemID(SubMenuid,2)
    if CloseAllid==4:
        win32gui.PostMessage(outwindow, win32con.WM_COMMAND, CloseAllid, 0)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        Quickselect=win32gui.FindWindow('TfrmStartup',None)
        win32api.PostMessage(Quickselect, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN,27, 0)
        win32api.PostMessage(Quickselect, win32con.WM_KEYUP,27, 0)
        time.sleep(0.5)
    Openbox=win32gui.FindWindow('#32770','æ‰“å¼€')
    if Openbox==0:
        Menuid=win32gui.GetMenu(outwindow)
        SubMenuid=win32gui.GetSubMenu(Menuid,0)
        Openid=win32gui.GetMenuItemID(SubMenuid,0)
        win32gui.PostMessage(outwindow, win32con.WM_COMMAND, Openid, 0)
        time.sleep(0.5)
    Openbox=win32gui.FindWindow('#32770',None)
    ComboBoxEx32=win32gui.FindWindowEx(Openbox,0,"ComboBoxEx32", None)
    ComboBox=win32gui.FindWindowEx(ComboBoxEx32,0,"ComboBox", None)
    Filenamebox = win32gui.FindWindowEx(ComboBox,0,"Edit", None)
    Filename=path+subpath+subpath+'-'+Number+'.p2dx'
    print(Filename)
    win32api.SendMessage(Filenamebox, win32con.WM_SETTEXT, 0, os.path.abspath(Filename))
    win32api.PostMessage(Filenamebox, win32con.WM_KEYDOWN,13, 0)
    win32api.PostMessage(Filenamebox, win32con.WM_KEYUP,13, 0)`
```

---

### the error is:

```
    `>C:\ProgramData\Bentley\Geotechnical\PLAXIS Python Distribution V1 Update 1\python\pythonw.exe -u "sand_excavation_output.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sand_excavation_output.py", line 135, in <module>
    output('D:\PLAXIS\Strut-Sand-AU14-Simulations','\COV=0.1-theta=1m\COV=0.1-theta=1m-001.p2dxdat',1,5) 
  File "sand_excavation_output.py", line 67, in output
    Closeandopen(Number,path,subpath)
  File "sand_excavation_output.py", line 26, in Closeandopen
    Menuid=win32gui.GetMenu(outwindow)
pywintypes.error: (1400, 'GetMenu', 'Invalid window handle.')
>Exit code: 1`
```

---

Comment: So this is failing in line 1. `outwindow` is invalid window handle, it means you didn't find right window, make sure it's not zero, and check with `win32gui.IsWindow`. The subsequent lines don't look promising. Did this work before? You should try UI Automation. I am not a python programmer, I think pywinauto is a good option.